# Property does not exist on type '{ $route(currentRoute: any): void; }' in Ionic Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework

so I'm current working on an Ionic WebApp with Vue and TypeScript. Right now, I try to get the current id, which is parsed by the route. For that, I was working on a watcher:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      productId: null,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    $route(currentRoute: any) {
      this.productId = currentRoute.params.id;
    },
  },
};
```

This is the error message I get:

```
[vue-cli-service] TS2339: Property 'productId' does not exist on type '{ $route(currentRoute: any): void; }'.
[vue-cli-service]     14 |   watch: {
[vue-cli-service]     15 |     $route(currentRoute: any) {
[vue-cli-service]   > 16 |       this.productId = currentRoute.params.id;
[vue-cli-service]        |            ^^^^^^^^^
[vue-cli-service]     17 |     },
[vue-cli-service]     18 |   },
[vue-cli-service]     19 | };
```

I already tried it with the handler notation, but this also didn't work. Does someone else have an idea?

Comment: what does the route look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
  watch: {
    "$route.params.productId": {
      handler: function(value) {
        this.productId = value
        console.log(value);
      },
      // deep: true,
      immediate: true
    }
  },
```

> Passing in immediate: true in the option will trigger the callback immediately with the current value of the expression

Answer (score 0):

To [enable type inference in components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage), use `Vue.extend()` on the exported component definition:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
                    
export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      productId: null,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route(currentRoute: any) {
      this.productId = currentRoute.params.id
    }
  }
})
```